# Excel "mmmm" formula in German

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How does the *mmmm* function work in German? I tried to find it on YouTube no luck.

I want to display the month not with a number but the actual month name. In English version it is `=text(Cell;"mmmm")`

What do I need to type in for *mmmm* in a German version of Excel?

Comment: Try a comma `,` instead of a semi-colon `;`

Comment: Got to Cell Number Formatting (Ctrl+1, Number tab). Choose Date from the left pane then a format mask from the right that represents something similar to what you want. Now click Custom from the left pane and the right pane/text box will show what is used in your regional language to represent the correct formatting mask.

Comment: Btw, in DE-DE a day is T, TT or TTTT and a year is JJ or JJJJ.

Answer (score 3):

```
=TEXT(cell;"MMMM")
```

The lower case `m` represents `minutes` (in the German number formatting codes)